# Class WP_Rewrite not found

Tags: ajax

Updating my WordPress to 4.4 I have that error:

> Fatal error: Class 'WP_Rewrite' not found

The page who have the error is my custom ajax with the following code:

```
<?php
// Constantes propias para ajax
define("SHORTINIT",true);
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', false);
if (!defined("AUTH_COOKIE")){
    define("AUTH_COOKIE",false);
}
if (!defined("LOGGED_IN_COOKIE")){
    define("LOGGED_IN_COOKIE",false);
}
require_once ("../../../../wp-load.php");
//Loading code from wp-settings after SHORTINIT    
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/l10n.php' );
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/formatting.php' );
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/capabilities.php' );
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/query.php' );
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/user.php' );
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/meta.php' );
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/general-template.php' );
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/link-template.php' );
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/post.php' );
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/comment.php' );
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/rewrite.php' );
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/script-loader.php' );
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/taxonomy.php' );
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/theme.php' );
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-wp-walker.php' );
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/post-template.php' );
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/post-thumbnail-template.php' );
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/shortcodes.php' );
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/media.php' );

create_initial_taxonomies();
create_initial_post_types();

require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/pluggable.php' );

wp_set_internal_encoding();
wp_functionality_constants( );

$GLOBALS['wp_the_query'] = new WP_Query();
$GLOBALS['wp_query'] = $GLOBALS['wp_the_query'];
$GLOBALS['wp_rewrite'] = new WP_Rewrite();
$GLOBALS['wp'] = new WP();
$GLOBALS['wp']->init();
wp();

if (!defined("WP_CONTENT_URL")){
    define("WP_CONTENT_URL",get_option('siteurl').'/wp-content');
}
require_once ('ajax-funciones.php');
// There I have some acctions

die();
?>
```

Before update Wordpress that works but now, I have the error with WP_Rewrite(). That class is in the file rewrite.php if you looking for in the codex and that is include.

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I can fixed the problem including this files:

```
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-wp-rewrite.php' );
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-wp-user.php' );
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-wp-tax-query.php' );
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-wp-meta-query.php' );
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-wp-term.php' );
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-wp-post.php' );
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-wp-roles.php' );
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-wp-role.php' );
```

Following the errors in the code and looking for in the wordpress codex.

Answer (score 1):

The `WP_Rewrite` class definition has been moved to it's own file:

```
/wp-includes/class-wp-rewrite.php
```

This is how it's included within the `wp-settings.php` file:

```
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-wp-rewrite.php' );
```

... but I'm a little bit scared of your setup and wonder why you need to do it this way, rather than using more native ways to get data from a WordPress site.

Comment: The reason was the speed of ajax...I used the shorinit because with a "normal" use of ajax spend 1,5 or 2 seconds in each consult. Looking for in the codex, I found too the solution, I will write that. Thanks @birgire